# rotate 3d structure

Tags: perl, vector, 3d, rotation

I have an array which contains 3d modeling information x, y, z coordinates for a structure rotated and placed in the desired stance. I also have a new array which has similar structure without the rotation or placement. The new structures coordinates begin at [0 0 0].
It is easy to get the first portion of the structure into the right place by adding the first element of the properly rotated array to the unstructured array. My problem now is the rotation. How do I rotate the new element so that it matches the angle in x, y and z of the properly rotated array? 
Thank you

Comment: Take a look at transformation matrices, specifically the rotation matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find three representative vectors *up*, *front* and *right* from the data then the rotation matrix would be:

```
[rx ux fx ox]
[ry uy fy oy]
[rz uz fz oz]
[ 0  0  0  1]
```

where O = [ox oy oz] is the origin

This is feasible if you know enough of the geometry of rotated structure.

Why it works is seen from the interpretation of identity matrix and rotation matrix:
In the reference coordinate system

```
 'Right' = [1 0 0 0], 
 'Up'    = [0 1 0 0],
 'Front' = [0 0 1 0],

 Multiplying each of these by the rotation matrix:
   [a d g 0]   Right*R = [a b c 0];
 R=[b e h 0]   Up * R  = [d e f 0];
   [c f i 0]   Front*R = [g h i 0];
   [0 0 0 1] 

 If there is no rotation, R = I == identity matrix; 

 Then Right * I = [1 0 0 0]; Up*I = [0 1 0 0 ]; Front*I = [0 0 1 0];
```

Conversely, if you know that your geometry contains a cube (perhaps even scaled...)
Then knowing which point in the array of rotated vertices corresponds to points
*o*, *F*, *R*, *U*,  and in the case of cube it's largely a matter of choice...

```
 U
 |
 |        ___---F
 |  ___---    
 o--
    --__
        --R
```

Front vector = (F-o)/|F-o|, Right = (R-o)/|R-o|, Up = (U-o)/|U-o|

Comment: thank you for the response..could you define up front right because without further information i cant implement this also could you provide a link that shows the validity of your answer

Comment: i tried to multiply by the rotation matrix but I'm missing something http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C0%2C0%7D%7D.%7B%7B1%2C2%2C2%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C2%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C2%2C2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D

Comment: "shoot" with your left hand: your index finger points to 'front', your thumb points to 'up'; then you can extend you middle finger to point 'right'. These define a left handed 'cartesian' coordinate system, where each finger/axis can be defined by a three coordinate vector in some "absolute" reference coordinate system.

Comment: You are trying to multiply 3x3 matrix with 4x4 matrix, which doesn't work. What should work is multiply a 4-element vector by that 4x4 rotation matrix, where the typical elements x,y,z are followed by a homogeneous element 'w', which is set to 1.0 before the matrix multiplication.

Comment: Will structural integrity remain the same no skewing or enlargement.. each vector move by a degree maintaining the same distance which they had before...only rotating?

Comment: No scaling, no skewing, if the vectors U,F,R are orthogonal and normalized. In that case I can also promise, that r * r' = I, where r is the top 3x3 matrix [a,b,c;d,e,f;g,h,i] and r' its transpose.